# mysql update query with 2 sub querys

Tags: mysql

Can anyone see what is wrong with the below query?
The Value I have is the products_model number 000011195001

What I need is the sum attributes_stock of all corresponding products_id in Table products_attribute

The sum of all attributes_stock of products_id 1726 in Table products_attribute is 500
These 500 need I in Table products in Field products_quantity

When I run it I get:

```
UPDATE products As C INNER JOIN (
SELECT SUM( attributes_stock ) AS products_quantiry
FROM products_attributes
WHERE products_id IN(
    SELECT products.products_id
    FROM products
    WHERE products_model LIKE '000011195001'
    )
) 
AS A ON products.products_id = products_attributes.products_id
SET C.products_quantity = A.products_quantiry
```

Table products
products_model, products_id,products_quantity

values

000011195001, 1726

Table products_attribute
products_id,attributes_stock

1726, 300

1726, 150

1726, 50

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

here (i have done a sql fiddle but the website isn't working right now :'():

```
   UPDATE products
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT  products_id, SUM(attributes_stock) as qty
 FROM products_attribute
 GROUP BY products_id) T ON T.products_id = products.products_id
 SET products.products_quantity = T.qty
 WHERE products_model = '000011195001'
```

;